# CONCATENATE cells in the column with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas

`CONCATENATE` cells in the column which separated by empty cells using `ARRAYFORMULA`. I have an idea but am not sure it is right. First of all get row number of first and last names for each day. Combine them in formula and finally put that formula to `ARRAYFORMULA`.

D2= `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>"",ROW(B2:B)+1,""))`

E2= `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C<>"",IF(C3:C="",ROW(B2:B),""),""))`

So the question is how to get the row number of the last name for each day in the same row as a day and how to combine this number to a formula which can be compatible with `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Example:

[image: Data sample]

Answer (score 0):

To get to the result (with steps in between) try (in a empty column in row 2)

```
=ArrayFormula(If(right(B2:B, 3)="day", offset(B2:B, 1,1)&", "&offset(B2:B, 2,1),))
```

and see if that works ?

Comment: it is works only for two names per day. in case 3 or more it is doesn't work